# How can I do a connection with Filter component and Card component

Tags: reactjs, filter, components

I'm trying to do a "connection" with my Filter component and my Cards component. The user should select the filter, it would only show the Cards with that filter selected.
When the user click in a filter button, it shows the specific Cards correct, but when the user click again in another filter, it dissapear all the Cards. Problably is something in the filter function but I can't figure out.

Here is the page:
[[image: project page]

Here is the Filter component:

```
import React from "react";
import Carrousel from "react-elastic-carousel";
import "./filtro.css";

function Filtro({ filtros, itensFiltrado }) {
  const breakPoints = [
    { width: 1, itemsToShow: 1, pagination: false },
    { width: 600, itemsToShow: 2, pagination: false },
    { width: 860, itemsToShow: 5, pagination: false },
    { width: 1100, itemsToShow: 5, pagination: false },
    { width: 1700, itemsToShow: 6, pagination: false },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="filtro__segmento">
      <Carrousel breakPoints={breakPoints}>
        {filtros.map((filtro, id) => {
          return (
            <label
              className="card__segmento"
              key={id}
              onClick={() => itensFiltrado(filtro)}
            >
              <h2 className="segmento__titulo">{filtro}</h2>
              <input type="radio" className="input-radio" name="teste" />
              <span className="check"></span>
            </label>
          );
        })}
      </Carrousel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Filtro;
```

The Father Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./popupOrcamentoSimultaneo.css";
import Filtro from "./Filtro";
import Card from "./Card";

import api from "../../../../api";

function PopupOrcamentoSimultaneo({ setOpenPopup, checkedState }) {
  const [profissionais, setProfissionais] = useState([]);
  const [filtroProfissionais, setFiltroProfissionais] = useState([]);
  const [filtros, setFiltros] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    "Olá! Vamos nos casar e gostariamos de mais informações sobre seu serviço."
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get("profissionais/listarTodos/").then(({ data }) => {
      setProfissionais(data);
      const setOfFilters = new Set(
        data.map((profissional) => profissional.segmento)
      );
      setFiltros([...setOfFilters]);
    });
  }, []);

  const itensFiltrado = (segmentoEmpresa) => {
    const novosProfissionais = profissionais.filter(
      (profissional) => profissional.segmento === segmentoEmpresa
    );
    setProfissionais(novosProfissionais);
  };

  let cardsProfissionais = profissionais;
  let listaCardsProfissionais = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cardsProfissionais.length; i++) {
    listaCardsProfissionais.push(
      <Card dadosProfissionais={cardsProfissionais[i]} />
    );
  }

  const changeValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="popup">
      <div className="popup__container">
        <div className="close-container" onClick={() => setOpenPopup(false)}>
          <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </div>
        <h2 className="popup__titulo">
          Solicite orçamento à outros profissionais simultaneamente!
        </h2>
        <Filtro filtros={filtros} itensFiltrado={itensFiltrado} />
        <h3 className="popup__subtitulo">
          Profissionais recomendados para você.
        </h3>
       <div className="cards__profissionais">{listaCardsProfissionais}</div>
        
        <div className="input-box">
          <label for="input" className="input-label">
            Escreva sua mensagem
          </label>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="input"
              className="input-text"
              placeholder="Olá! Vamos nos casar e gostariamos de mais informações sobre seu serviço."
              value={value}
              onChange={changeValue}
            />
            <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PopupOrcamentoSimultaneo;
```

The Card Component (if necessary):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./card.css";

function Card(props) {
  let nomeEmpresa = props.dadosProfissionais.nomeEmpresa;
  let segmento = props.dadosProfissionais.segmento;
  let valorMinimo = props.dadosProfissionais.valorMinimo;
  let cidade = props.dadosProfissionais.cidade;
  let estado = props.dadosProfissionais.estado;
  let idProfissional = props.dadosProfissionais.idProfissional;
  let imagemVitrine = props.dadosProfissionais.imagemMarketplace;

  let nomeArquivo = imagemVitrine ? imagemVitrine : "no-image.png";

  /*  const imagemVitrineProfissional = require(`../../../../../fileContents/imagensVitrineProfissional/${imagemVitrine}`); */

  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState({});

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setCheckedState((p) => ({ ...p, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card__profissional" key={idProfissional}>
        <div className="card__header">
          <img
            className="card-imagem"
            src={imagemVitrine}
            alt={`${nomeEmpresa}`}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="card__body">
          <h2 className="card__titulo">{nomeEmpresa}</h2>
          <span className="tag">{cidade}</span>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label className="checkbox-label">
              Solicitar Orçamento
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox-input"
                name={nomeEmpresa}
                value={nomeEmpresa}
                checked={checkedState[nomeEmpresa] || false}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
              />
              <span className="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="botao-orcamento">
        Solicitar Orçamento (
        {Object.keys(checkedState).filter((i) => checkedState[i]).length})
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Card;
```